# find a list of integers for a checksum

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I would need a list of *n* positive integers **L** that has following properties:

- for each possible subset **S** of **L**, if I sum all items of **S**, this sum is not in **L**
- for each possible subset **S** of **L**, if I sum all items of **S**, this sum is unique (each subset can be identified by his sum)

Working example 1:

```
n = 4
L = [1, 5, 7, 9]

check:
1+5   = 6  ok
5+7   = 12 ok
7+9   = 16 ok
9+1   = 10 ok
1+7   = 8  ok
5+9   = 14 ok

1+5+7 = 13 ok
5+7+9 = 21 ok
1+5+9 = 15 ok
1+7+9 = 17 ok

1+5+7+9 = 22 ok

All sums are unique -> L is OK for n = 4
```

Comment: why don't you try with prime numbers?

Comment: @WasiAhmad Just using primes doesn't gurarantee it. E.g., 5+13=7+11.

Comment: "for each possible subset S of L, if I sum all items of S, this sum is not in L" What if that subset contains only one element? From your example, it seems you only consider subsets with 2 or more elements? Please confirm.

Comment: @tobias_k  yes 2 or more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an easy to construct sequence, I suggest using *power series*, e.g.

```
 1, 2,  4,  8, ..., 2**k, ...
 1, 3,  9, 27, ..., 3**k, ... 
 1, 4, 16, 64, ..., 4**k, ...
 ...
 1, n, n**2, n**3,..., n**k, ... where n >= 2
```

Take, for instance, `2`: neither power of `2` is a sum of other `2` powers; given a `sum` (number) you can easily find out the subset by converting `sum` into binary representation:

```
 23 = 10111 (binary) = 2**0 + 2**1 + 2**2 + 2**4 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 16
```

In general case, a simple *greedy algorithm* will do: given a `sum` subtract the largest item less or equal to the `sum`; continue subtracting up to zero:

```
 n = 3
 sum = 273

 273 - 243 (3**5) = 30
  30 -  27 (3**3) =  3
   3 -   3 (3**1) =  0

273 = 3**5 + 3**3 + 3**1 = 243 + 27 + 3
```

Comment: Great answer..!

Comment: @dmitry are u suggesting that, if we have a set S of powers of 2 & if we want to find any target T as in subset sum problem will be just a simple problem of converting the T to binary?

Comment: @Bhagwan Parge: Yes, in case of powers of `2` we can use binary representation; in general case, for an *arbitrary* powers `n >= 2` we can use greedy algorithm

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, What about something like below,

63
126
252
504
1008
2016

We can convert this to base to & then find the subset having target sum T.

Is this already discovered?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, sorry asking again, 
has anybody tried converting, any random set into powers of 2 set, so searching of the target sum T becomes trivial & ultimately P = NP.